# Where is the 64 bit NetBeans Design GUI?

Tags: netbeans

I had to replace jre and jdk 32 versions with 64 bit version since I am developing on a 64 bit machine and needed to get serial IO working.
The 64 bit NetBeans Design GUI seems to have vanished since I upgraded from 32 to 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: uninstalled then re-installed NetBeans.